# ValueError: could not convert string to float: XX

Tags: python, numpy

I am running the following codes:

```
from numpy import *
import operator


def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    arrayOLines = fr.readlines()
    numberOfLines = len(arrayOLines)            #get the number of lines in the file
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))        #prepare matrix to return
    classLabelVector = []                       #prepare labels return
    print numberOfLines

    index = 0
    for line in arrayOLines:
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        print index
##        print listFromLine
##        returnMat[index ,0] = listFromLine[0]
        returnMat[index,:] =['XX','XY','XZ']
##        returnMat[index ,2] = listFromLine[2]
##        returnMat[index ,3] = listFromLine[3]
        classLabelVector.append(listFromLine[0])
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

the 2nd code is:

`import my_bayes as kNN
    datingDataMat,datingLabels = kNN.file2matrix('train.txt')`

the error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: XX`
```

Comment: well yes, 'XX`' is not a float. can your show the file?

Comment: Please post the __full__ traceback. Showing the file content would be helpful as well.

Comment: file contains data like below:17100000 1808989 CONTRACTORS - BPA POSITIONS North Sea
28121100 1559931 Direct Secondary Freight LubricantsThe

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
returnMat[index,:] =['XX','XY','XZ']
```

sets all your **matrix** values to strings.

Comment: I think problem in this code in the following portion:returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))

Comment: Try changing the line to `returnMat[index,:] =[0 ,1, 2]` and rerunning your code!

Comment: Its running continuously like infinite loop:

Comment: That depends on what you are doing with the values afterwards but you are no longer getting the cannot convert error.